# How can NiFi handle burst data?

Tags: apache-nifi

If the submitted data to NiFi are not coming in a steady flow (but on bursty) how can NiFi handle them? Does it use a message broker to buffer them? I haven't seen anything like this in its documentation.

Answer (score 3):

NiFi connections (the links between processors) have the capability of buffering FlowFiles (the unit of data that NiFi handles, basically content + metadata about that content), and NiFi also has the feature of backpressure, the ability of a processor to "tell" the upstream flow that it cannot handle any more data at a particular time. The relevant discussion from User Guide is [here](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Connecting_Components).

Basically you can set up connection(s) to be as "wide" as you expect the burst to be, or if that is not prudent, you can set it to a more appropriate value, and NiFi will do sort of a "leaky bucket with notification" approach, where it will handle what data it can, and the framework will handle scheduling of upstream processors based on whether they would be able to do their job.

If you are getting data from a source system that does not buffer data, then you can suffer data loss when backpressure is applied; however that is because the source system must push data when NiFi can not prudently accept it, and thus the alterations should be made on the source system vs the NiFi flow.